# Writing an integrated C/Java program and keep getting "fatal error: 'jni.h' file not found"

Tags: c++, java-native-interface, java-home

I am on MacOS and am having a problem that has been asked before on here numerous times. After several hours of trying all solutions, I am unable to get this error

```
fatal error: 'jni.h' file not found
```

to go away. I included in the file I am trying to compile

```
#include <jni.h>
```

and my makefile has my JAVA_HOME set to $JAVA_HOME

```
JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-16.jdk/Contents/Home
```

Comment: The value of the `JAVA_HOME ` environment variable is completely irrelevant for how the c++ compiler is looking up the path where `jni.h` should be found. Show us a [mcve], especially of how the c++ code is built.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure to properly configure build environment.

Take a look here to learn how to build simple `JNI` based code in `macOS`

https://github.com/mkowsiak/jnicookbook/tree/master/recipes/recipeNo001

In general, what you want to have is setting `-I` during compilation

```
-I${JAVA_HOME}/include -I${JAVA_HOME}/include/darwin
```

You can also use `Xcode` to build library: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WEA-3uI7Y18